# Shopify Variant Product - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, shopify, variant, error-code

I am working on a Shopify website and am trying to shut off subscription options for 4 packs.

I have this code, but I'm getting an error I'm unfamiliar with. Hoping someone could point me in the right direction to fix. Thanks!

**Website:**
https://crispandcrude.myshopify.com/products/mellow-mule  ( **password**: *susahx* )

**Error:**
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

[image]

**Code:**

```js
/* ======================================
    DISABLE 4 Pack Subscriptions
========================================= */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

  let noSub = '4 Pack'
  let variants = document.querySelectorAll('[data-value]');
  let rechargeForm = document.querySelector('.rc_container')
  let initialCheckedValue = document.querySelector('.swatch input:checked')


  // On variant change
  variants.forEach(variant =>
                   variant.addEventListener('click', e=> {
    if (e.target.value == noSub) {
      // Hide RC widget and click first/one time option          
      rechargeForm.style.display = 'none'
      document.querySelector('.rc_widget__option--onetime input').click();
    } else {
      rechargeForm.style.display = 'block'
    }
  })
                  )

  // On first load
  if (initialCheckedValue.value == noSub) {
    // Hide RC widget and click first/one time option
    rechargeForm.style.display = 'none'
    document.querySelector('.rc_widget__option--onetime input').click();
  } else {
    rechargeForm.style.display = 'block'
  }

});
```

Comment: The recharge form is using ShopifyScripts API, so it's not ready on DOMContentLoaded. You need to see if there is a global event that recharge uses to inform that the form is loaded or you can use Mutation Observer to check when the content for the form is updated with the recharge one.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your rechargeForm with document.getElementById("DivID"). Note: update the id as per your need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#DivID{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<button onclick="clickFunction()">Click here to hide</button>

<div id="DivID">
This section will hide after click
</div>


<script>
function clickFunction() {
    document.getElementById("DivID").style.display = "none";
}
</script>  

</body>
</html>
```